# Как убрать утечку памяти?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, memory, утечка-памяти

У меня приложение Погода

Смотрите код, потом обсудим

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView city;
private TextView temperature;
private TextView details;
private ImageView imageView;

private Weather weather = new Weather();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    city = findViewById(R.id.city);
    temperature = findViewById(R.id.temperature);
    details = findViewById(R.id.details);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.weather_icon);

    try {
        weather.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Yerevan&appid=53328692679f840d7be7c1d520a324d1").get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.change_city) {
        showInputDialog();
    }
    return false;
}

private void showInputDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Change city");
    final EditText inputCity = new EditText(this);
    inputCity.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    builder.setView(inputCity);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Change", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            try {
                Weather weather = new Weather();
                weather.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + inputCity.getText().toString() +
                        "&appid=53328692679f840d7be7c1d520a324d1").get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}


public class Weather extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private String result = "";
    private HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                result = result.concat(String.valueOf(current));
                data = reader.read();
            }
            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject info = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("main"));
            JSONObject wind = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("wind"));

            double temper = Double.parseDouble(info.getString("temp"));
            int temp_Celsius = (int) (temper - 273.15);
            String pressure = info.getString("pressure");
            String humidity = info.getString("humidity");
            String windSpeed = wind.getString("speed");
            String place = jsonObject.getString("name");

            String weather = jsonObject.getString("weather");
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(weather);
            String description = "";
            int id = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject arrayObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                description = arrayObject.getString("description");
                id = arrayObject.getInt("id");
            }

            setWeatherIcon(id, jsonObject.getJSONObject("sys").getLong("sunrise") * 1000,
                    jsonObject.getJSONObject("sys").getLong("sunset") * 1000);

            city.setText(place.toUpperCase());
            temperature.setText(String.valueOf(temp_Celsius + "°C"));
            details.setText("Weather: " + description + "\n" + "Pressure: " + pressure + "hpa" + "\n" + "Humidity: " + humidity + "\n" + "Wind speed: " + windSpeed + "m/s");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setWeatherIcon(int actualId, long sunrise, long sunset) {
        int id = actualId / 100;
        long currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        if (actualId == 800) {
            if (currentTime >= sunrise && currentTime < sunset) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sun);
            } else imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.night);
        } else {
            if (currentTime >= sunrise && currentTime < sunset) {
                switch (id) {
                    case 7:
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.partly_cloudy);
                        break;
                }
            } else if (currentTime <= sunrise && currentTime > sunset) {
                switch (id) {
                    case 7:
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.night_cloudy);
                        break;
                }
            } else switch (id) {
                case 2:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunder);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.storm);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rain);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.snow);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cloud);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Так, сперва эти классы были отдельно друг от друга, тогда все View элементы студио требовал делать `static`, пробовал исправить и интерфейс создал, но в итоге не смог, решил вместить их в один класс! Так работает, но ругается только на классе Weather.. This AsyncTask class should be static or leaks might occur. Как можно исправить это, только тут есть утечка памяти, делать его статик не надо. Помогите чем сможете, спасибо!!

Answer (score 3):

> Ругается не на утечку, а на её возможность и правильно делает.

Дело в том что ваш класс это Activity имеет инер класс AsyncTask тем самым имеет неявную ссылку на него, но проблема в том, что сам Android и компонент Activity имеют свой жизненый цикл. Что это значит?

1. При #уничтожении# активити, Async может жить, и будет вызывать классы с нулевой ссылкой, те NPE.
2. Рабочий Async будет задерживать GarbageCollector что приведет к сильной утечке. И потенциально к OutOfMemory
3. Вы можете запустить несколько раз Async, и это может привести к нарушению консистентности данных, утечке.

**Решение:**

1.Сделать iner class статичным.

2.Вынести Async выше на уровень (сделать отдельный класс)

Вот один из примеров:

```
private static class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private WeakReference<MyActivity> activityReference;

    MyTask(MyActivity context) {
        activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // do some long running task...

        return "task finished";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        // get a reference to the activity if it is still there
        MyActivity activity = activityReference.get();
        if (activity == null) return;

        // modify the activity's UI
        TextView textView = activity.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        textView.setText(result);

        // access Activity member variables
        activity.mSomeMemberVariable = 321;
    }
}
```

Comment: А если его делать статик, это норм? Ну такое разрешается?

Comment: @AnunAzganun  
я стараюсь не использовать Async, обычно встречаю его в чужом коде. но в вашей ситуации на мой взгялд это самое правильное решение, тем более это рекомендация самой IDE, так что да - это норм.

Comment: Спасибо вам))))